# Differential Topology - Passing Smoothly to the Quotient

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* includes the following theorem (Thm. 4.30):

> Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds and $\pi : M \to N$ is a surjective smooth submersion. If $P$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary and $F : M \to P$ is a smooth map that is constant on the fibers of $\pi$, then there exists a unique smooth map $\tilde{F} : N \to P$ such that $\tilde{F} \circ \pi = F$.

He proves this by using the related result for topological spaces and quotient maps to construct $\tilde{F}$ uniquely as a continuous map and then verifies that it is smooth by a characteristic property (Thm. 4.29). But this seems like overkill. Wouldn't it suffice to construct $\tilde{F}$ uniquely as a simple set map, without involving the topology of quotient spaces at all?

Comment: How would you know that $\tilde{F}$ is smooth then?

Comment: The characteristic property that Lee uses in the proof only requires $\tilde{F}$ to be a set map.

Comment: Yes, that would suffice.